# How to print specific number of tables per page?

Tags: css, django, printing, html-table, jinja2

While I was working on a project I needed to generate around 2000 small tables which I also have to print in pages. I was generating those tables via using a for loop within my django project using jinja code.Here I am attaching a sample code-

```
{% load static %}
{% load tempos %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bcard/bcard.css' %}">
    <title>bcoutput</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for i in 30|get_range %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        <table class="table pagebreak table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">First</th>
              <th scope="col">Last</th>
              <th scope="col">Handle</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">2</th>
              <td>Jacob</td>
              <td>Thornton</td>
              <td>@fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">3</th>
              <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
              <td>@twitter</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css file I am using is:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}

@media print {
    body {
        width:100%
        height:100%
    }

    table {
        width: 30% !important;
        height: 50% !important;

    }

.pagebreak {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}

}
```

Now, the problem I am facing is-I want to generate 6 tables in three columns per page while printing the pages. But, no matter what I do in the css section it isn't giving me the proper result.The ongoing print preview is-

[image]

Is there anyone to help ?

Comment: If you know how many tables fit on a page you could add a `<p style="page-break-before: always">` every n pages to force a page break

Comment: Thanks GTBebbo for your suggestion.Tried but hasn't changed a thing.